# Minimal number of nodes in a complex line arrangement.

Tags: co.combinatorics, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a collection of $n$ lines. Assume that $\mathcal{A}$ is not a pencil.  It is known (see http://www.springerlink.com/content/320p742475v6q746/) that if all lines are in $\mathbb{RP}^2$, then there are at least $6n/13$ nodes.

What is the minimal number of nodes, if all lines are in $\mathbb{CP}^2$?

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshots saved on the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a paper by Hirzebruch "Singularities of algebraic surfaces and characteristic numbers", Cont. Math. vol. 58, part I, 1986, there is an inequality for the number of double and triple points of an arrangement of $n$ complex lines.
Denote by $t_k$ the number of points lying on precisely $k$ lines; if $t_n=t_{n-1}=t_{n-2}=0$, then 
$$t_2+3t_3/4\ge n+\sum_{r\ge 5}(2r-9)t_r.$$
This inequality is obtained from the Bogomolov-Miyaoka-Yau inequality for surfaces of general type: taking a suitable cover of the plane branched on an arrangement not satisfying the  inequality above and  desingularizing one would obtain a surface of general type with $c_1^2>3c_2$.

Comment: You're welcome. You should also have a look at Giancarlo Urzua's Ph.D.'s thesis, he has a section about line arrangements.